# Try catch block issues

Tags: try-catch

My code doesn't terminate at catch block and never return "ERROR" even though I feed cases where
the input will never match "song", "joke" or "story". And always returns me the chatbot's name. Is there a reason why???

```
String execute(String command) {
    String result = "";
    try{                                                                                        
        switch(command) {                                                                      
            case "song":
                result += " sings: Like a Rolling Stone ...";                                                                                                   
                break;
            case "joke":                                                                             
                result += " says: Why are Communists bad Java programmers?They dont't like classes.";                                                                                   
                break;                                                                      
            case "story":                                                                              
                result += " says: A long long time ago ...";                                        
                break;                                                              
        } 
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            return "ERROR";
    } 
    return this.ChatBotName + result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the code is running currect and never throw any error that can be caught. No matching branch in **switch** statement is not an error. You can check more details about the **switch** statement from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using try and catch block can you not use default case from switch case.

```java
String execute(String command) {
    String result = "";                                                                        
    switch(command) {                                                                      
        case "song":
            result += " sings: Like a Rolling Stone ...";                                                                                                   
            break;
        case "joke":                                                                             
            result += " says: Why are Communists bad Java programmers?They dont't like classes.";                                                                                   
            break;                                                                      
        case "story":                                                                              
            result += " says: A long long time ago ...";                                        
            break;  
        default:
            return "ERROR";
            break;                                                
    } 
    return this.ChatBotName + result;
}
```